# Count number of records in lmdb databse with python

Tags: python, lmdb

I open a `lmdb` database using this code:

```
    lmdb_env = lmdb.open(source_path, readonly=True)
```

How can I count the number of records in this database?

Comment: I don't understand the close votes. Just because a question is short or basic, that doesn't mean it's too broad or unclear. This is a straightforward, specific question about coding that can have a definite correct answer, and I see no reason why it's inappropriate for Stack Overflow's format. I'm voting to reopen. I respectfully ask in advance that anyone who votes to leave closed please post a comment explaining why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a simple solution using `for` loop. Here it is:

```
count = 0
for key, value in lmdb_env.cursor():
        count = count + 1
```

However, I think there should be a better way using pre-defined function.

Comment: `sum(1 for _  in lmdb_env.cursor() )`

Answer (score 8):

I think it should be like this:

```
lmdb_env = lmdb.open(lmdb_file_name, readonly=True)
print lmdb_env.stat()
```

Then it prints the directory that [Jaco](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34420565/1714410) pasted here.

Answer (score 3):

```py
    env = lmdb.open('db file path', max_dbs = ' > 0')
    with env.begin() as tx:
        db = env.open_db(b'db name', txn=tx)
        print(env.stat()) 
        print(tx.stat(db)) # this gives stats about one specific db
```

`env.stat()` gives entries of the main database. `tx.stat(db)` gives entries of one named database.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `event.stat()`. It will return the following dictionary with `entries` detailing the number of records in this database:

```
{'branch_pages': 1040L,
'depth': 4L,
 'entries': 3761848L,
 'leaf_pages': 73658L,
 'overflow_pages': 0L,
 'psize': 4096L}
```