# how to append data to existing LMDB?

Tags: python, machine-learning, caffe, pycaffe, lmdb

I have around 1 million images to put in this dataset 10000 at a time appended to the set.

I"m sure the map_size is wrong with ref from this [article](http://deepdish.io/2015/04/28/creating-lmdb-in-python/)

used  this line to create the set

```
env = lmdb.open(Path+'mylmdb', map_size=int(1e12)
```

use this line every 10000 sample to write data to file where X and Y are placeholders for the data to be put in the LMDB.

```
env = create(env, X[:counter,:,:,:],Y,counter)


def create(env, X,Y,N):
    with env.begin(write=True) as txn:
        # txn is a Transaction object
        for i in range(N):
            datum = caffe.proto.caffe_pb2.Datum()
            datum.channels = X.shape[1]
            datum.height = X.shape[2]
            datum.width = X.shape[3]
            datum.data = X[i].tostring()  # or .tostring() if numpy < 1.9
            datum.label = int(Y[i])
            str_id = '{:08}'.format(i)

            # The encode is only essential in Python 3
            txn.put(str_id.encode('ascii'), datum.SerializeToString())
        #pdb.set_trace()
    return env
```

How can I edit this code such that new data is added to this LMDB and not replaced as this present method replaces it in the same position.
I have check the length after generation with the env.stat().

Comment: If you know the length and know that all existing records have ids less than the length, why can't you replace the line `str_id = '{:08}'.format(i)` by `str_id = '{:08}'.format(existing_length + 1  + i)`?

Comment: Thanks you this worked :) @SudeepJuvekar

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Le me expand on my comment above.

All entries in LMDB are stored according to unique keys and your database already contains keys for `i = 0, 1, 2, ...`. You need a way to find unique keys for each `i`. The simplest way to do that is to find the largest key in existing DB and keep adding to it.

Assuming that existing keys are consecutive,

```
max_key = env.stat()["entries"]
```

Otherwise, a more thorough approach is to iterate over all keys. ([Check this.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34420375/count-number-of-records-in-lmdb-databse-with-python))

```
max_key = 0
for key, value in env.cursor():
    max_key = max(max_key, key)
```

Finally, simply replace line 7 of your `for` loop,

```
str_id = '{:08}'.format(i)
```

by

```
str_id = '{:08}'.format(max_key + 1 + i)
```

to append to the existing database.

Comment: As the keys are sorted, why not use `last()` then `key()` to find the largest key?